# Maven2 - Deploy only master pom

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have a master POM which has many modules defined in it.

I want to make some minor changes to the master POM and deploy the new Master POM to our nexus instance.

Everything is confgured ok to allow this, but when I do a mvn clean install deploy all the modules are built and deployed too. I dont want this.

How do I tell maven to just deploy the master POM and not build/deploy the modules? Can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this option:

```
-N,--non-recursive            Do not recurse into sub-projects
```

Reference:  http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html